# Swift 3 - loading multiple ViewControllers at launch

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, loading

I am working on making a tabbed app. It has a TabBarController and 4 ViewControllers attached to it.

By default, at launch only `FirstViewController` is loaded. I would like to load both `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` at start before switching to the second view via tab menu.

What i tried so far is that I created custom `MyTabBarController` class and tried to use

```
var sv = SecondViewController()
sv.loadView()
```

in `ViewDidLoad()`, but it caused a fatal error during loading, because (my guess) mapView element from storyboard was not loaded.

What is the correct way to simultaneously load the two viewControllers which use storyboard elements? All my other tries have not been successful so far.

Comment: Are you creating your UITabBarController programmatically?  If so, you can programmatically create each of your view controllers and assign them to the `viewControllers` property of your tab bar controller.  But this isn't a typical design pattern.  May I ask why you're trying to do this?  Is it for performance reasons (to pre-load the second controller to avoid a delay)?

Comment: Hmm, if i'm getting your question correctly - I created TabBarController it in storyboard, then created `MyTabBarController: UITabBarController` class and assigned it to storyboard element. I did only as a possible means to load 2 View Controllers at once, since i thought it's required. The reason why i'm need them loaded at the same time is exactly about avoiding a delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your main view controller

```
var secondViewController:UIViewController!
```

And in your viewDidLoad:

```
secondViewController: UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! SecondViewController
```

That's it. When you want to present it, use:

```
self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No problem @AliceA.! Mark it as correct answer so other people that are facing the same issue can fix it.