# Start second view controller of navigation stack first

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

There is a default calendar app.

It starts with the next view controller and back button is already there like there some other view controller was started before this one:

[image]

When you press back button you get the next view controller:

[image]

How did they do it?

In my app I need the same logic (to start a view controller with the latest or default category but users can press back button to select a different category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to do this, I would start by simply using `pushViewController(animated:)` to push the month view onto the navigation stack, with `animated: false` in the root view controller's `viewWillAppear(animated:)` method. The calendar would appear to the user already one level deep in the navigation stack.

So, the first controller is the year view, and then the month view is the second one pushed onto the stack, but it all happens before the user has seen any of the views. Simple, right?

Here are [the docs for UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) in case that helps.

Comment: I was trying with `show(controller, sender: self)` but there was animation. So, yes, with `pushViewController(animated:)` it looks much better. It seems that I have to use some bool variable in root view controller to indicate that the second view controller was already started and check add condition in `viewWillAppear(animated:)`. And the root view controller won't die while the second view controller is active?

Comment: You could use a Bool, or you could use `navController.viewControllers.contains(yourViewController)` to see if the controller is already in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to push the view controllers once at start. An easy way to do it is to sub-class `UINavigationController` and assign it to the root navigation controller in your storyboard. Then simply do the work in your sub-class' `viewWillAppear` method, as this will be called exactly once at startup.

Of course, you can also accomplish the same result by using a flag to only load the next view controller once if you put the push code in the first view controller's `viewWillAppear`.

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation MyNavigationController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
    [self pushViewController:secondVC animated:NO];
}

@end
```