# Swift preload collection view from second tab at launch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, loading

I've already found in SO several answers on how to pre-load all tab views when app launches with either this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261776/how-to-load-all-views-in-uitabbarcontroller) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280977/swift-3-loading-multiple-viewcontrollers-at-launch) but nothing seems to work.

With both of these solutions, second tab view is clearly loaded from first tab however (simple print checking) however I've noticed collectionView datasource methods are not called. 
I want to avoid the slight delay before photos are populated into collection view, this is why I want to load second tab when app launches.

It clearly seems that assets are fetched for the first time (in ViewDidLoad method) when second tab view appears and not before when instantiated in first tab as requested.

Any ideas ?

thanks.

Comment: You will need to analyze the situation a bit more or extract your code to create a minimum that is needed to reproduce your issue. Many things may have gotten wrong and members here may only keep shooting in the dark like "are all your cell at index path being called at view did load", "have you checked that when the new controller appears it is indeed by pointer confirmed that it is the same object"...

Comment: well i've just checked and both collectionview datasource methods 1/number of items in section and 2/cellforItem are not called.

Comment: So you might want to call `reloadData` on collection view. If you already do that also check its frame. If view is too small it will not display cells and will not call those methods for it. Try resizing the view controller or something I guess.

Comment: I'm already calling reloadData, still not working and checked frames as well and they are correctly sized. So basically now the question would be why collectionView datasource methods aren't called..

Comment: Well is its `dataSource` non-null and valid? At least some `numberOff` method should be called then so the next is checking if you return non-zero values on it.

Comment: I'll try this, how do you implement this method? thanks

Comment: There are 2 methods `numberOfItemsInSection` and `numberOfSections` in data source. You will probably just need to put some breakpoint in them...

Comment: both of these methods are not called at all, the variable from where the data is taken is definitely not empty but neither of these datasource methods are called.

Comment: Than at the point you call `reloadData` I assume that `collectionView.dataSource` is `null`.

Comment: well any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Calling `collectionView.dataSource = self` before calling `collectionView.reloadData()` should be enough.

Comment: it's already done, the problem is not here I suppose because collectionView is correctly populated when second tab appears.

Comment: Did you solve it? Having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[3] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0].viewWillAppear(true)
```

Change 3 to the index of the designated tab bar.

In the designated view controller put your reloading code in the viewwillappear
such as

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```